# Why do I get Active record relation instead of Array in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm running tests on `Post`:

`expect(subject.query).to eq [previous_post, post, future_comment]`

But I get this error :

```
expected: [#<Post id: 3, body: "Sed quis aut harum. Asperiores ad commodi tempore ...", ...>]


got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 3, body: "Sed quis aut harum. Asperiores a.....>]>
```

It expected an array but get an active record object. How can I resolve that ?

This is the code i'm testing :

```
      def query
        scope = Post
                .where(user_id: user.id)
                .my_scope
                .my_other_scope
                .includes(:body)

        scope = case @options[:order_by]
                when "older"
                  order_by_older(scope)
                when "most_discussed"
                  order_by_most_discussed(scope)
                else
                  order_by_older(scope)
                end

        scope
      end
```

Comment: You can do `subject.query.to_a`

Comment: Do you want your method to specifically return arrays? Is there a dependency?. As someone has already mentioned where returns active_record relation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can update your spec to use.

```
expect(subject.query).to contain_exactly(previous_post, post, future_comment)
```

If its a dependency in your code then you can convert it to an array using 
`.to_a` as mentioned by @MrYoshiji

I do not recommend converting it to an array if it can be avoided, reason being it slower.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're using `where`, instead `find` or `find_by`, when using where then you get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` as result - response, no matter if the query returns one or more results.

If you need a single Post object then consider using `find`, or in case using `where`, make sure of specifying any *specific* element inside.

You could try with (not tested):

```
def scope(user_id)
  Post.find_by(user_id: user_id).my_scope.my_other_scope.includes(:body)
end

def query(user_id)
  order = @options[:order_by]

  return order_by_older(scope(user_id)) if order == 'older'
  return order_by_most_discussed(scope(user_id)) if order == 'most_discussed'

  order_by_older(scope(user_id))
end
```

Comment: Actually I want to get multiple posts not just one. So where should be the best method, what do you mean by : "specify any specific element inside".

Comment: By specific element inside I mean by index, any element corresponding to an index in the result.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand :/

Comment: _Finder methods that return a collection, such as where and group, return an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation. Methods that find a single entity, such as find and first, return a single instance of the model_. If you need an array containing different objects, MrYoshiji's comment might help.